# How to use alias for whereIn in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im trying to use `whereIn()` method in laravel 5.2 but suddenly it returns a `column not found error`.

**Controller**

```
$users = \App\User::select([
    DB::raw('(CASE WHEN users.id < 4 THEN users.id ELSE "" END) as user_id')
]);

$users->whereIn('user_id', [1,2,3]);

return $users->get();
```

**Error**

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id'

Answer (score 0):

the whereIn can be apply only on a column, since you do not have that column, simply make it!

you can do this using sub query then [join it](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins):

```
 $query1 = $users = \App\Models\User::select([
            DB::raw('users.id as id_to_join,(CASE WHEN users.id < 4 THEN users.id ELSE "" END) as user_id')
        ]);
        $value=User::joinSub($query1,'query1',function ($join){
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'query1.id_to_join');
        })->whereIn('user_id', [1,2,3])->get();
```

in case your laravel version did not support joinsub, you can do it using query builder:

```
 $value=DB::table('users')->join(
            DB::raw('(select users.id as id_to_join ,(CASE WHEN users.id < 4 THEN users.id ELSE "" END) as user_id from users)subJoin')
            ,function($join){
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'subJoin.id_to_join');
        })->whereIn('user_id', [1,2,3])->get();
```

Comment: Can I use `joinSub()` method for laravel 5.2 version?

Comment: 5.2 ... it's too old is not? however 5.8 does:
https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_joinSub

Comment: Yeah, too old but I cannot upgrade it since it is not my own laravel app. And it is not necessary to upgrade. Maybe there's a tweak around to get the expected result

Comment: I have done it using query builder, I hope it helps

Comment: Im getting empty result when I use your updated code.

Comment: strange, I have test it, maybe something wrong in query name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227514/discussion-between-omr-and-jonjie).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be that user ID values greater than 3 are to be disregarded.  If so, then just check the `id` column directly in your call to `whereIn()`:

```
$users = \App\User::select([
    DB::raw('(CASE WHEN users.id < 4 THEN users.id ELSE "" END) as user_id')
]);
$users->whereIn('id', [1,2,3]);
return $users->get();
```

If you really needed to reuse the alias in the same level of the query, avoiding a subquery, you could use MySQL's overloaded `HAVING` clause:

```
$users = \App\User::select([
    DB::raw('(CASE WHEN users.id < 4 THEN users.id ELSE "" END) as user_id')
]);
$users->havingRaw('user_id in (1,2,3)')
return $users->get();
```

Comment: What if I want to use the alias instead of calling it directly? For example in the future if I have joined table and have a bit complex `CASE WHEN` conditions, I need to use the alias.

Comment: You could use `HAVING` in this case.

Comment: Do we have `orHavingRaw` in laravel?

Comment: @Jonjie [Yes it does](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#havingraw-orhavingraw).

Comment: Im using laravel 5.2, I think it is not indicated on the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries